# Setting up a Maven Project that Utilizes Artifactory

Tags: maven

Hello I am new to Maven and am trying to create a Maven project that:

Has dependencies that only Pull from Artifactory

Have artifacts only publish to Artifactory
    Can change where artifacts are published (Integration or Dev)
Artifact published can be used as Dependencies

When published to Integration the maven pom file will be able to pass credentials, that is not accessible/viewable in the build output

Connection to artifactory not required to build/publish (Can publish locally)

Project can be built on the command line without eclipse on the machine

Currently this is the code I have for the Maven Pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://artifactory/artifactory/webapp/home.html?2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://artifactory/artifactory/webapp/home.html?2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://artifactory/artifactory/webapp/home.html?2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://artifactory/artifactory/webapp/home.html?2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
  <url>http://artifactory/artifactory/webapp/home.html?2</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>Test</groupId>
      <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm more than certain this isn't set up correctly as this is my first time using Maven.

Edit: I have been reading from the Jfrog site that was suggested and while it has somewhat helped I am still not certain if what I have is correct by any means.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<!-- The Basics -->
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>...</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>Test</groupId>
      <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <parent>...</parent>
  <dependencyManagement>...</dependencyManagement>
  <modules>...</modules>
  <properties>...</properties>

<!-- Build Settings -->
  <build>...</build>
  <reporting>...</reporting>

<!-- More Project Information -->
  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>
  <description>...</description>
  <url>http://artifactory/artifactory/webapp/home.html?2</url>
  <inceptionYear>...</inceptionYear>
  <licenses>...</licenses>
  <developers>...</developers>
  <contributors>...</contributors>

<!-- Environment Settings -->
  <issueManagement>...</issueManagement>
  <ciManagement>...</ciManagement>
  <mailingLists>...</mailingLists>
  <scm>...</scm>
  <prerequisites>...</prerequisites>
  <repositories>
      <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://artifactory/artifactory/webapp/home.html?2</url>
          <snapshots>
              <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
      </repository>
      <repository>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <url>http://artifactory/artifactory/webapp/home.html?2</url>
          <releases>
              <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
      </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://artifactory/artifactory/webapp/home.html?2</url>
          <snapshots>
              <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
      </pluginRepository>
      <pluginRepository>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <url>http://artifactory/artifactory/webapp/home.html?2</url>
          <releases>
              <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
      </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
      <id>ArtifactoryDeploy</id>
          <name>ArtifactoryDeployThing</name>
          <url>http://artifactory/artifactory/webapp/home.html?2</url>
  </distributionManagement>
  <profiles>...</profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: I suggest you read [this document](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Maven): it will guide you through every step of setting up Maven with Artifactory.